# SQLITE. Не обновляется поле в таблице

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite

Я сделал счетчик голосования и хочу теперь ограничить пользователей, что бы у каждого пользователя был только 1 голос, для этого я создал 3 поля: usr_id, post_id, last_vote. last_vote принимает -1 (против), 1 (за), None (пользователь голосует впервые). Но после голоса поле last_vote не переходит из состояния None в 1.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT last_vote FROM likes WHERE post_id = (?)",
(abs(data),)) # Tuple - force
last_vote = cursor.fetchone()

if data > 0:
    if last_vote == None: # first vote
        likes_count += 1
    elif last_vote < 0:
        likes_count += 1
        dislikes_count -= 1 # remove previous vote
    last_vote = 1
elif data < 0:
    if last_vote == None: # first vote
        dislikes_count += 1
    elif last_vote > 0:
        dislikes_count += 1
        likes_count -= 1 # remove previous vote
    last_vote = -1

cursor.execute("""UPDATE posts SET
likes_count = ?, dislikes_count = ? WHERE id = ?""",
(likes_count, dislikes_count, abs(data),)) # Tuple - force

cursor.execute("UPDATE likes SET last_vote = ? WHERE post_id = ?",
(last_vote, abs(data),)) # Tuple - force
connection.commit()
connection.close()
print(last_vote) # None
```

DDL

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS likes(
user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
post_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
last_vote INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, post_id),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES posts (id) ON DELETE CASCADE)""")
```

Comment: Не заметил у вас обновления этой таблицы от слова совсем.
`insert into likes....... on duplicate key update .....` ибо update сработает только если пользователь уже голосовал(т.е. запись уже есть но вы хотите ее изменить)

Comment: *last_vote принимает -1 (против), 1 (за), None (пользователь голосует впервые)* Либо Вы заранее в таблицу вставляете пары id всех имеющихся пользователей и постов (а также пачку новых при создании того или другого) - во что я лично не верю, либо вставляете конкретную пару юзер-пост при первом голосовании юзера за данный пост - тогда какой нафиг None, если записи тупо не было...

Comment: @Akina Ко всему этому есть еще и вопрос, что такое `None`, если поле объявлено как `INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`